# Problems with JS and Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, as a review, we are making a mechanism to evaluate with five star marks, but there are problems that the number of stars increases before the page and five stars.
[image]

As you can see, the number of stars increases steadily as you go through the pages.
I'd like to solve this problem, but I do not know how to solve it.

view

```
<div class="listing-rate" id="average_star_rate"></div>

<script>
  $('#average_star_rate').raty({
    path: '/assets',
    readOnly: true,
    score: <%= @listing.average_star_rate %>
  });
</script>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: I guess some javascript code render the stars multiple times.

Comment: Your code is being executed multiple times, try putting `alert('hello')` in the script to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing an issue common with Turbolinks. Remove Turbolinks from your application.js (or application.coffee) and try it again. Once you're stable, add Turbolinks and read the Turbolinks docs to ensure you don't run into this in prod. :)

Comment: Thank you so much. I turned off Turbolinks and it went well.　Thank you for answering.